# how to Send mail throught Google App script - Mail Merge Code

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to use the Google script's mail merge code to send the mail, as given the link.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge

I copy the complete code as it is but when I run it, it show No recipient error. when i debug the code it shows email address and body all the values, but fail to send mail.

my code is for send mail is

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  // [START apps_script_gmail_email_data_range]
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 4);
  // [END apps_script_gmail_email_data_range]

  // [START apps_script_gmail_email_template]
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  // [END apps_script_gmail_email_template]

  // [START apps_script_gmail_email_objects]
  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
  var objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);
  // [END apps_script_gmail_email_objects]

  // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
  // it to the appropriate person.
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = objects[i];

    // [START apps_script_gmail_email_text]
    // Generate a personalized email.
    // Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
    // the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
    var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
    // [END apps_script_gmail_email_text]
    var emailSubject = 'Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge';
    const  email = rowData.emailAddress;
    // [START apps_script_gmail_send_email]
   MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress , emailSubject, emailText);
   
 
    // [END apps_script_gmail_send_email]
  }
}
```

[Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h06wB.png)

Please help me to correct this code.

Regards
Jitender

Answer (score 0):

**1. The code snippet you provided relies on an additional function - `getRowsData()`**

While you did not include this function, this might be the problem causer - and is not mapping the actual value of the email to the key `rowData.emailAddress`.

It would be easier to just skip this function and define:
`var objects = dataRange.getValues();`

Then, to send the email, instead of `email = rowData.emailAddress` define `email = rowData[2]` - that is, simply define that the email is located in the third column of your data range.

Do the same for the rest data if applicable - keep in mind that `rowData` is an array, and arrays start with index `0` (so the first column is `rowData[0]`).

**2. Probably the script loops through empty rows (that do not contain a valid recipient - thus the error message).**

This can be due to the method `dataSheet.getMaxRows()`, which also retrieves empty rows.

You can easier replace it with `dataSheet.getLastRow()` to retrieve only rows that have contents or define

`var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange()`

which automatically detects the contents containing range in the sheet.

Comment: Hi , Can you help me.  There is no problem with Object. it is showing correcly while I am debugging. please check my above reply.

Comment: Thank you for providing additional informaiton. Just beware that you should provide it by either [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64353388/edit) your original post or in a comment - not by providing an answer (unless it is an answer). I am not quite sure by what you mean with "save as another variable" and "blank". What about if before `MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress , emailSubject, emailText);` you insert the line `Logger.log("The row is: " + (2+i) + "and the email address is: " +  rowData.emailAddress);` and then, after execution, go on `View->executions` and view the logs?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to get value from object. It is showing email address, name and DOB correctly in Debug window see in attached screen. But when i am going to save this email address value in other variable , it shows blank. If send mail then shows no recipient error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH4ht.png)